# TypeError: User.findOne is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

i'm making an api nodejs, and i want to make a login with jwt, i already create the model and the route, i'm testing it on postman with method post, i have a collection called "user" on mongodb but when i send the petition post appear this error  `

```
TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
    at E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\routes\loginRoutes.js:8:27
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at app.use (E:\AppAgricola\Proyecto\api\app.js:27:5)`
```

i send user and password field on postman

```
                var express = require('express');
                var router = express.Router();
                var User = require('../models/user');
                var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

                router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

                    let promise= User.findOne({username:req.body.username}).exec();

                    promise.then(function(doc){
                        if(doc){
                            if(doc.isValid(req.body.password)){
                                let token = jwt.sign({username:doc.username}, 'secret', {expiresIn: '3h'});
                                return res.status(200).json(token);

                            }else{
                                return res.status(501).json({message: 'invalid credentials'});
                            }    
                        }else{
                            return res.status(501).json({message:'User email is not registered'})
                        }
                    });

                    promise.catch(function(err){
                        return res.status(501).json({message:'some internal error'})
                    })
                })
```

### module.exports = router;

this is the model

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var schema =  new Schema({
        username:{type:String, require:true},
        password:{type:String, require:true},
        //creation_dt:{type:String, require:true}
    },
);

schema.statics.hashPassword = function hashPassword(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
}

schema.methods.isValid = function(hashedpassword){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(hashedpassword, this.password);
}
```

module.export = mongoose.model('User', schema);
i want that the method post return a jwt

---

this is the method "isValid" inside the model, like you can see, i have a console.log() that show me the variable "this.password" and "hashedpassword", this variables are equal, and this method must return a boolean=true but return "false", i don't get what happen:

```
schema.methods.isValid = function(hashedpassword){
    console.log(this.password)
    console.log(hashedpassword)
    var data = bcrypt.compareSync(hashedpassword, this.password);
    console.log(data)
    return bcrypt.compareSync(hashedpassword, this.password);
}
```

Comment: This will depend on what and how values are exported from `models/user.js`. Can you also share that snippet?

Comment: Jonathan, i already update the post

Comment: Possibly a typo – plural [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/modules.html#modules_exports) vs. singular in `user.js`.

Comment: but this is like "user" in the model, "user" in routes and "user" in mongodb collection

Comment: I mean the spelling of `exports` itself. `users.js` is assigning to `export` rather than `exports`, creating a new property that isn't passed along by Node.

Comment: thanks Jonathan, it was a mistake, but right now when i test with postman the method "isValid" return "false", i going to update the post to you can look best

Answer (score 1):

`module.export = mongoose.model('User', schema);` doesn't export anything.

Node.js (not ES6) export is:

```
module.exports = ...;
```

Whatever at the triple dots is the returning value for 'require' function.

Comment: but i have another model and it works, with: module.export = mongoose.model('User', insumoSchema);   ....schema is a variable where is the model like insumoSchema

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to change

`import User from '../../models/User';` (which was added automatically to the imports by VSCode)

to `const User = require('../../models').users;`

Hope this helps people with similar case.

Comment: Actually, I already had that, I just missed .users; at the end ... Took me a while to figure it out :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the export is correct.

this is what worked for me:

```
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `console.log(module.exports)` like if:

```
module.exports=User=mongoose.model('User',Schema);
```

if it prints the schema, then it's working and morover the issue lies in the `module.exports` only.